# How to prevent clang-format from adding newlines between stream operator calls <<

Tags: c++, clang-format

We are currently in the process of formatting our code base with `clang-format`. We found a situation where for some reason the stream operator to `std::cout` is moved to the next line if two consecutive strings literals are present. Putting a variable in between thw two string literals causes clang-format to not change the format. What needs to be changed in the `.clang-format` file to avoid this?

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "something" << "something" << std::endl;
}
```

becomes

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "something"
              << "something" << std::endl;
}
```

while

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    std::cout << "something" << a << "something" << std::endl;
}
```

stays untouched.
Note while this last snippet is wider, it is *not* split across multiple lines, while the shorter snippet above is.

This is with LLVM 9.0.0 Windows installer and is reproducible with the default config file.

Comment: line breaks are introduces by clang format only when line reaches some columns count limit. This means that by anonymizing sample code, you shortened lines by different length and you hidden actual reason why one line was wrapped and other was not wrapped by clang format.

Comment: The thing is, by adding << a, I actually increase the line length, so it should also add a line break in the last example. But it doesn't. Only if I have two char * streamed after each other does it break into two. These examples are even longer than the actual code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior can't be altered via the `.clang-format` file, as it is part of the code.

This behavior was introduced in this commit:
https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/df28f7b8dd6a032515109de4ff5b4067be95da8e

Link to bug report: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45018

Comment: Stunning. Quoting a commenter of that commit: _"...it would be good if this was optional. Not all people want their code formatted like this..."_